# how to create state properties from an array in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to setState of a component from an array of values.

I have these values on `filtersSelected` array->

```
["name", "date", "state"]
```

I want to set these values to my state like this

```
myState = {
...etc,
name: null,
date: null,
state: null
}
```

I tried using

```
this.setState(previousState => ({
  ...previousState,
  ...filtersSelected: null
}))
```

apparently it doesn't work.Can anyone help me?

Comment: You really need to publish the whole component.  There are a lot of things that could be wrong here, but it's hard to tell from the isolated parts.

Answer (score 2):

In order to spread the array into an object you first need to convert the array into an object and then you can spread the object keys into the state:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    ...filtersSelected.reduce(function(acc, item) {
        return Object.assign(acc, {[item]: null})
    }, {});
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things to note here. First of all, when you call `setState`, you do not need to provide all of the previous state. `setState` "merges" the specific state properties that you pass into the already existing state.

It also might be helpful to make your filters selected array an object, as you are trying to use the spread , but is by no means necessary. If you want to keep the array, you can use the code below.

```js
let filtersSelected = ["name", "date", "state"];
this.setState({name: filtersSelected[0], date: filtersSelected[1], state: filtersSelected[2]});
```

Or, if you make `filtersSelected` into an object (which I highly recommend), you can do:

```
let filtersSelected = {name: "name", date: "date", state: "state"};
this.setState(filtersSelected);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your array to object first then use a loop to assign values to your newly created object.

```
let filteredSelected = ["name", "date", "state"];
let obj;

for(let i of filteredSelected){
    obj[i] = null;
}

this.setState(previousState => ({
  ...previousState,
  obj
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has his own way, here are some ways I like

```
  let data = ["name", "date", "state"];
  Object.values(data).map(i => this.setState({ [i]: null }))
```

But I don't like to iterate setState for each element

```
  let data = Object.assign({}, ...["name", "date", "state"].map((prop) => ({[prop]: null})))
  this.setState(data)
```

Or you can do like so

```
this.setState(["name", "date", "state"].reduce( ( accumulator, currentValue ) => ({...accumulator,[ currentValue ]: null}), {} ));
```